# MySQL force index doesn't work

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm running a simple left join query between relatively small tables (~5000 rows):

```
select *
from table1
left join table2 
force index (index_table2_on_name) for join 
on table1.name = table2.name
```

index_table2_on_name exists, but Mysql refuses to use it. Running explain on the query returns: select_type = SIMPLE, type = ALL and possible_keys = NULL for both tables.

Any idea?

Comment: forcing an index to be used is usually a bad idea...More often than not it will come back to bite you...

Answer (score 7):

Found the problem.
It appears that table1.name and table2.name had different character sets defined.
It's weird that Mysql ignores the index instead of using a conversion.

Comment: Not really - it does the same thing with different types